# How to Alter Column from nvarchar(max) to nvarchar(50)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an existing table in SQL SERVER 2008 with one of its column as NVARCHAR(MAX) and it only has values of less than 10 characters in it.
This table is in production and has data in it.

I have got a requirement wherein I have to Alter this column from NVARCHAR(MAX) to NVARCHAR(50). T**he SQL Server gives some Truncation error while doing this operation**, even though the data in that column is less than 10 characters.

This is my script:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table] ALTER COLUMN [Column1] NVARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL
```

Comment: What is the *exact* error? Are you sure the data is really less than 10 characters? Try querying for rows `WHERE LEN(Column1)>50`. Also note that `NVARCHAR(MAX)` is the type used to store *blobs*, and SQL Server may not allow the type change. That's why you should post the full error message

Comment: "the data in that column is less than 10 characters" - are you sure? It's easy to have trailing blanks. Please run SELECT * FROM dbo.TABLE WHERE LEN(Column1) > 50.

Comment: Also, is it really an error, or is it a warning?

Comment: Hmmmmm - to add to my above comment - LEN does not count trailing blanks (as per SQL standard, which surprisingly Microsoft obeys this time), so you have to use DATALENGTH instead. Since it's Unicode (**N**VARCHAR), each character is two bytes, so check `WHERE DATALENGTH(Column1) > 100`

Comment: I am 100% sure the column data is less than 10 characters. But as you said LEN() does not count blank spaces, I will need to recheck. But in any case there will not be any data loss if truncation happens successfully.

Comment: I am look for some pure SQL script based approach to forcefully truncate column data and convert it to NVARCHAR(50)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I believe NVARCHAR(MAX) is meant for storing CLOB and not BLOB. For BLOB we use VARBINARY(MAX)

Comment: @Prado if you know about BLOB/CLOB, you know that it's fundamentally a different storage format and SQL Server may not allow the conversion. Use `DATALENGTH` instead of `LEN`. There is no point looking for some kind of bug or limitation if your data actualy has tralining spaces. If it does, use TRIM or RTRIM *first*, then alter the data type

Comment: Let me give you some more background about my code. I have C# enum AddressType.Line1. Now this "Line1" is less then 50 characters and also since its in VARCHAR(MAX) column, it wont have trailing space in it. Now wouldn't SQL Server allow me to convert this column in VARCHAR(50)

Answer (score 5):

First Check Your table data with this query:

```
SELECT DATALENGTH(Column_Name) AS FIELDSIZE, Column_Name 
FROM Table_Name
```

If everything is fine, you may have checked the `Prevent Saving Changes` option.   Follow these steps to check:

**Tools >** **Designers** Uncheck **Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation**

Comment: The Prevent Saving Changes is only valid if you are using that awful table designer. It would be much simpler to write the alter table statement instead.

Comment: This requires access to Management Studio on production databases. I need some SQL Script based solution.

Comment: If you have live server connection string try to connect by your sql server.
Open run and type ssms then enter you server name,
Authentication is SQL Server Authentication 
Login and password and this details you have already used in you project connection string after this apply the changes. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure that you wouldn't lose data, then:

```
Update myTable set myNVMaxCol = left(coalesce(myNVMaxCol,''),50);
Alter table myTable alter column myNVMaxCol nvarchar(50) not null;
```

Comment: Alternatively, move the data to a new column, delete the old comun and then rename.